# How to display text string in user control at design time?

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I am creating a user control that contains a panel as well as 4 string and integer properties.  I would like to display the text of the properties in the user control during design time.  How do I do this?  I am having a hard time finding examples.

Comment: I feel dumb.  Here is what the code is.

        If DesignMode Then
            Me.lblPageNum.Visible = True
        Else
            Me.lblPageNum.Visible = False
        End If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd question, the usual problem is hiding a property.  Make it look something like this:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class UserControl1

    Private mAardvark As Integer

    <DefaultValue(0)> _
    Public Property Aardvark() As Integer
        Get
            Return mAardvark
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            mAardvark = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Amy, it's hard to tell exactly what you're after.

When you have properties in user controls you can see and edit those properties in the Properties Window in design view.

So if you take nobugz answer in the properties window you will be able to set a value for the property Aardvark.

Is what you're asking that you want to see the value of the property in something like a text box?

If that is the case you need to make sure that the value returned from the property is a value i.e. not nothing! And that the property is set in an event like Load.

Also at design time the usercontrol view does not draw the values, if you drop the control on a form you will be able to see the values of your properties in a text box.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are asking, but I have assumed you want to display the property text in the control at design-time and hide this at run-time.

If this is the case, you will need to update the Label.Text value whenever the property value changes.

I have assumed that your control includes a Label named lblPageNum and a property PageNum.

```
Public Class TheUserControl

Private myPageNum As String

Public Property PageNum() As String
    Get
        PageNum = myPageNum
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        myPageNum = value
        ' This is where we set the value of the label at design-time
        lblPageNum.Text = myPageNum
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub

Private Sub UserControl1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Me.DesignMode Then
        Me.lblPageNum.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.lblPageNum.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class